# Import contacts from yahoo in python

Tags: python, django, yahoo, yahoo-api

Is there are official way to import contacts from user address book from yahoo?

For google it's really simple as:

```
import gdata
contacts_service = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsService()
contacts_service.email = email
contacts_service.password = password
contacts_service.ProgrammaticLogin()
query = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsQuery()
query.max_results = GOOGLE_CONTACTS_MAX_RESULTS
entries = contacts_service.GetContactsFeed(query.ToUri())
```

Is there such simple way for yahoo?

I found some solutions, that don't use api and looks strange for serious game - for example [ContactGrabber](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ContactGrabber/0.1). 
I found solutions, that require BBAuth Token in [django-friends app](https://github.com/jtauber/django-friends).

But, I want official, clear, way to grab user contacts from yahoo. Does it exists?

UPD: 
Finally I am avoiding use of yahoo api, and using [django-openinviter](https://github.com/tschellenbach/DjangoOpenInviter) for my purposes.

But I am still looking for examples of importing user contacts using api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Contacts REST API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html) is pretty straight-forward. The URL that you're after is

```
http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{guid}/contacts.json
```

Here is a script that will extract things for you. You can expand this to include authentication.

```
import urllib2
import json

def get_contacts(guid):
    url = 'http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{}/contacts.json'.format(guid)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return json.load(page)['contacts']['contact']
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you improve your solution and tell, how to get guid?

Comment: You can get a user's guid by making an HTTP GET request to http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid when the user is logged in. See  http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/introspective-guid-resource.html

Comment: This was a big help! Thanks. I didn't realize they had this API and the YQL API (which was much harder to use).  I think you need to leave off the ".json" at the end and replace it with "?format=json" though.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo has some decent documentation on how to access its APIs with Python [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-rest.html).  The information there will tell you how to access Yahoo APIs by YQL with http requests.  This means directly performing the http GETs and POSTs and parsing the results yourself.  However, they also have a python library that wraps those calls [here](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-python), but it has not been updated since 10/13/2009, so your mileage may vary.